# Add a user to a specific blog when they register?

Tags: multisite, users, user-registration

I've setup a WP MU site and I need to know how to sign up a user to a specific blog when they register. As it is now, if a visitor is visiting a specific site and they click the register button they are taken to the main network site and then they are given the option to register as a user or create their own blog.

I can create my own registration page but I'm not sure how to add that user to a specific site.

This is what I have so far:

```
$meta = apply_filters( 'add_signup_meta', array() );
$emailSent = wpmu_signup_user( $user_name, $user_email, $meta );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found it,

```
<?php add_user_to_blog( $blog_id, $user_id, $role ) ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_to_blog

Answer (score 0):

This works if you do not have a confirmation email, but you then have to hook activation to use `add_user_to_blog`. WordPress will add a user to an existing blog (now known as a network site) on user activation if you provide a couple of meta data fields:

```php
<?php
$user_blog_id = 2; // or get_current_blog_id(), etc.
$user_meta = [
    'add_to_blog' => $user_blog_id,
    'new_role' => 'subscriber' // or any other role your site has...
];
// WordPress has a built-in action on activation to look
//     for the above fields and assign the user to a
//     given blog id (network site) and role.
\wpmu_signup_user( $user_name, $user_email, apply_filters( 'add_signup_meta', $user_meta ) );
```

See [add_new_user_to_blog](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_new_user_to_blog/) for more information (this is the function called through an action on user activation that assigns the user to a blog [network site] using the meta fields in the example above).